# R Plot of Two Detrended Series Shows Line Chart Rather Than Scatterplot

Tags: r, economics

I have a set of data which are within the exact same time frame, with the exact same number of points. I have detrended both so comovement can be analyzed. When I plot them against each other the graph attempts to create a line chart including dates.
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VccCc.png)

This is what the series look like in the environment:
[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3CL7.png)

This is what the data looks like:
[data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKuKm.png)

I would like this in a scatterplot measuring against both variables, just points and no lines or dates in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

So I sorta figured it out but it's super botched and I do not recommend anyone else to do this.

Essentially, I bound the two datasets together doing:

```
testvar <- cbind(dewagerealM, dewagerealF)
```

I was then able to select all the data on the left and the right, then plot them against each other like so:

```
plot(testvar[1:23,1], testvar[1:23,2])
```

This seems to have worked but it's not pretty and definitely not what should be done but it seems to have gotten the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the options `xy.lines` and `xy.labels` set to `FALSE`

```r
plot(dewagerealM, dewagerealF, type = 'p',xy.lines = FALSE, xy.labels = FALSE)
```

Since you are plotting time series (ts) type objects, the help function `help("plot.ts")` can give you more details on the options you can use to plot these objects.